# What is the pythonic/faster way to declare module-level constants with computed values?

Tags: python, module

I'm writing a utility module for easy handling of data text files. I have declared some module-level constants to provide default values to my methods arguments since for now I only use these values but I want my code to be easily adaptable.

But some constants aren't easily hard-coded. For example `re`'s `pattern` objects I can only get with `re.compile`. So I've written

```
import re

_my_fine_pattern_string = r"some obnoxious regex"
MY_FINE_PATTERN         = re.compile(_my_fine_pattern_string)

def spam(eggs):
...
```

It worked yesterday within a script I directly execute. But now I wonder. Will this code be executed on `import`? Will it slow the execution? Will I be burned for doing this? Is there a better/faster way to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is fine. It will be executed on import. If you have a significant amount of computation to do (which `re.compile` isn't), it will slow down the import -- but this is as it should be, since you need the constants to do your work anyway.

Why are you using double-underscore names? If the constants are meant to be exported they should not be prefixed with underscores, and if not then they should have a single underscore. (Double has a specific meaning in the context of class inheritance but shouldn't generally be used anywhere else.)

Comment: Oh okay, I thought that double underscore was the idiom for "not to be exported". And the compiled pattern shouldn't have one. I edit the question. Thanks.

Comment: Sidenote to @Evpok - a full list of the python underscore conventions can be found by searching for "single_leading_underscore" within [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). The main reason "__attr" isn't used in modules is that the distinct behavior of "__attr" vs "_attr" is only needed for classes, so the shorter one is preferred in modules. Otherwise, that would make perfect sense :)

Comment: Oh, didn't see that we I've read it. Though I don't like all of these recommendations, this one is indeed quite obvious. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Module-level constants should always be named with `UPPER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES` (see the [Python Style Guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)!).

```
MY_FINE_PATTERN_STRING = r"some obnoxious regex"
MY_FINE_PATTERN = re.compile(_my_fine_pattern_string)
```

It absolutely will be executed on import. It really depends on the setup you're performing. In most cases like this, where you're doing minor setup operations like pre-compiling a `re` pattern, the resource hit is trivial.

Don't worry about pre-optimizing right now. Finish your code and if you run into bottlenecks, [profile](http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html#module-pstats) your code to find out what is causing it.

Comment: Question edited. The pattern string shouldn't be public so it would be `_underscored_lowercase`, only the compiled pattern will be `UPPER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES`.

I do have to optimize my code as much as possible, these are meant to be applied on large transcriptions (+100 000 lines) of speeches and I want to avoid having to refactor my code. Though I didn't know that profile thing, I'll read this doc. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It will be executed at import, don't worry. AFAIK it's the best way if your regex is to be used quite often.